Pourquoi construire les phrases en trompe-l'oeil, en plaçant le sujet de manière déroutante à la fin de : que, le pronom objet, le verbe ?
Ces deux phrases trompent l'oeil en nous amenant faussement à analyser « nous » comme pronom sujet. Une fois lu « a fait », alors on se rend compte que « nous » n’est pas un pronom sujet ! Il faut relire la phrase pour traiter « nous » comme le pronom objet direct, avec le sujet à la fin.

[1] Nous reproduisons ci-dessous telle quelle la traduction que nous a fait parvenir le mouvement.


[2] Ce texte est une discussion critique de l’entretien que nous a fait parvenir notre ami Claude Zylmans et que nous reprenons ci-dessous.

Mais pourquoi  emberlificoter le lecteur, en mettant le sujet à la fin ? Ces écrivains sont-ils délibérément obscurantistes ? Pourquoi ne pas écrire de manière plus compréhensible?

[1.1] Nous reproduisons ci-dessous telle quelle la traduction que le mouvement nous a fait parvenir.


[2.1] Ce texte est une discussion critique de l’entretien que notre ami Claude Zylmans nous a fait parvenir ...


Ces phrases ne sont pas des phrases trompe-l’œil (invariable) pour un francophone qui n'interprète pas nous comme un pronom sujet dans ces phrases.

Le verbe biter me semble trop familier pour une question. Pas de problème dans le [chat] mais en le lisant ici, des apprenants pourraient penser qu'il serait acceptable dans un registre courant alors que ce n'est pas vraiment le cas. Dans un registre relâché, tu peux utiliser capter à la place. D'autre part, obscurantiste est trop fort ici, délibérément obscurs suffirait.

Quelle langue(s) n'utilise(nt) pas ce style de tournure ? Elle me semble tout à fait habituelle dans les quelques-unes que je connais.

La tournure ne trompe pas les lecteurs natifs, même à l'oral. La proximité entre nous, 1ère pers. pluriel et a fait 3ème pers. singulier est le principal indice que le sujet du verbe n'a pas encore été énoncé.

À noter aussi, "nous" est complément d'objet indirect dans les deux exemples. Cela dit, bienvenue sur fr.SE et +1 pour le choix de poster en français.

La question a été posée et le poseur (jeu de mots) s'est barré, en laissant derrère lui (?), seulement c'est question.   L'aspect un peu drolatique c'est ceci: "en nous amenant faussement à analyser « nous » [...]. Comment amène-t-on quelqu'un faussement à faire quelque chose?

Comme indiqué dans les autres commentaires, c'est une structure usuelle pour les personnes dont le Français est la langue maternelle. Elle est même préférable lorsque le sujet est accompagné d'une subordonnée. Exemple : J'ai lu la traduction que nous a envoyé le professeur X que j'ai contacté sur recommendation du comité. –

Oui, pas de trompe-l'oeil ici, tout est normal.

@jlliagre  Ce n'est pas que obscurantiste soit trop fort, c'est un emploi inapproprié ici, probablement que le  le PO ne connait pas le sens du mot. Ta suggestion est bonne.

Cette forme n'est-elle pas un genre de cataphore ?

Il y a plusieurs cas en français où le sujet est placé après le verbe dans des phrases déclaratives. C'est parfois obligatoire, c'est parfois facultatif.
Dans les deux phrases citées dans la question c'est facultatif. Ce sont des propositions subordonnées relatives dont le pronom relatif est complément du verbe de la relative. Dans ces phrases le lien entre le sujet et le verbe n'est pas plus privilégié que celui entre le complément et le verbe. Il ne peut pas y avoir de confusion entre le sujet et le complément parce qu'en français le verbe se conjugue et un francophone rapproche spontanément le verbe de son sujet, que ce soit à l’écrit ou à l'oral.
Cette inversion se fait d'autant plus que le groupe sujet est composé de plusieurs mots. Si les deux phrases suivantes sont équivalentes à l'oreille d'un francophone :


Nous reproduisons ci-dessous la traduction que nous a fait parvenir le mouvement.
Nous reproduisons ci-dessous la traduction que le mouvement nous a fait parvenir.


La phrase :

Ce texte est une discussion critique de l’entretien que nous a fait parvenir notre ami Claude Zylmans.

sera privilégiée par rapport à :

Ce texte est une discussion critique de l’entretien que notre ami Claude Zylmans nous a fait parvenir.

Pour autant les deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes.
Il n'y a pas qu'avec les propositions relatives introduites par un pronom relatif complément d'objet que l'inversion peut se produire. On la trouve aussi dans les subordonnées introduites par une pronom relatif complément circonstanciel.

Nous avons piqueniqué dans un champ dans lequel paissaient des vaches  grasses et paisibles.

Est préférable à :

Nous avons piqueniqué dans un champ dans lequel des vaches grasses et paisibles paissaient.

à cause de la longueur du groupe sujet.
Par contre on ne peut pas faire l'inversion si le sujet est un pronom :
Nous avons vu des vaches grasses et paisibles, nous avons piqueniqué dans le champ dans lequel paissaient elles.
Seule la phrase suivante est correcte :

Nous avons vu des vaches grasses et paisibles, nous avons piqueniqué dans le champ dans lequel elles paissaient.


Pour la dernière phrase, j'aurais dit : "Nous avons vu des vaches grasses et paisibles, nous avons piqueniqué dans le champ dans lequel elles paissaient." même si j'ai du mal à dire pourquoi. Avec l'article indéfini je tique ><'

@AloisChristen Très juste, merci. Trop concentré sur la syntaxe ce qui n'est pas un détail m'avait échappé. C'est logique que nous les avons vues parce que nous étions justement dans le champ où elles étaient.

C'est une tournure idiomatique en français, surtout à l'écrit. Il y a même plus drôle :
C'est la carte que nous nous sommes envoyée depuis notre séjour à la montagne.
Ici il n'y a pas d'alternative évidente à part peut_être :
C'est la carte que nous avons envoyée à notre adresse depuis ...
Mais c'est sensiblement plus lourd. Noter que dans les deux cas envoyée s'accorde avec la carte qui est le Complément d'Objet Direct placé avant...
